# Create a Json array in a for loop - php

Tags: php, loops, arrays

```
<?php
include '../connection.php';

$sql="SELECT userid,name,batch FROM dbusers";
$results=mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot execute query");
$count=mysql_num_rows($results);
$arr=array();
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($results);
//What to put here ?
}
json_encode($arr);

?>
```

This is my php code. I want to ask what to put inside the for loop so that I can create a an array of array in php. The inner array will have userid, name and batch as its elements .

Answer (score 3):

> What to put here ?

`$arr[] = $rows;`

Full code

```
<?php
include '../connection.php';

$sql="SELECT userid,name,batch FROM dbusers";
$results=mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot execute query");
$count=mysql_num_rows($results);
$arr=array();
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $rows=mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC);//use MYSQL_ASSOC so you wouldn't have duplicate data
    $arr[] = $rows;
}
$json = json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include '../connection.php';

$sql     = "SELECT userid,name,batch FROM dbusers";
$results = mysql_query($sql) or die("Cannot execute query");
$arr     = array();

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

try this.