# Add comma Json from php

Tags: php, json

I have an array inside a foreach to generate data in json, but I should add a comma to validate the code. But I can not ... how can I do it?

```php
$obj = array(
    'name' => 'value', 
    'img' => 'value', 
    'url' => 'value',
);

echo json_encode($obj);
```

I have this code

```json
{"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"}
{"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"}
{"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"}
```

but I would like this code

```json
[
    {"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"},
    {"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"},
    {"name":"value","img":"value","url":"value"}
]
```

Comment: Use `$obj[] = array(...);` to make object into an array of those.

Comment: I already tried but it happens a strange thing ... they are added these] incorrectly .... I tried this code .... but the last comma does not make me validate the code     $obj = array(
        'name' => 'value', 
        'img' => 'value', 
        'url' => 'value',
            );

        $json = json_encode($obj);
        
        echo $json;
        
        echo ',';

Comment: _"they are added these] incorrectly"_ - I doubt that json_encode added anything incorrectly. It's more likely that you made some mistake when built the array. Show us that attempt and we can help you sort it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14251490/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/6739871/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17097136/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/44379007/2943403

Answer (score 2):

Don't echo the JSON in the loop. Put all the objects in another array, and convert that to JSON.

Start with an empty array:

```
$array = [];
```

In the loop push onto that array:

```
$array[] = array(
    'name' => 'value', 
    'img' => 'value', 
    'url' => 'value',
);
```

After the loop is done, do:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: @gracekweb Instead of editing the title as solved, mark the answer that helped you solve it as solution.